# Keep aspect ratio then fill: object-fit aspect-ratio fill-available

Tags: css

[image: A list of 2 related content cards: the first one is wide and shows an image to the left with a nice aspect ratio, the second card has limited width causing the text to reflow, increasing the card's overall height, the image's aspect ratio is maintained but it's now half the height of the card.]

The image uses `object-fit: cover; aspect-ratio: 16/9;` which is great until the card's limited width causes the text to reflow and changes the overall height. Now the aspect-ratio is maintained but the image height is half that of the card.

I've found that `height: -webkit-fill-available;` works nicely, but I can't seem to find any alternatives for non-webkit browsers.

[image: A list of 2 related content cards: the first one is wide and shows an image to the left with a nice aspect ratio, the second card has limited width causing the text to reflow, increasing the card's overall height, the image's aspect ratio is ignored and the image takes the available height.]

Suggestions?

Here's the code https://codepen.io/MediaFormat/pen/zYLQjrb

EDIT: @Temani Afif suggestion helped solve this:
`min-height: 100%:`

Comment: share your code structure

Comment: forgot to paste the codepen link, https://codepen.io/MediaFormat/pen/zYLQjrb added it to the Q as well

Comment: height: 100% instead of fill-available?

Comment: `height: 100%` didn't work, but `min-height: 100%` worked, cheers!